# Windows for Docker で Docker fileのCOPYできない

Tags: docker

Docker for WindowsでDockerを勉強しています。(Linuxの知識は1本毛が果てる程度です)

Docker fileでCOPY文を使ってファイルをコピーしようとしましたができませんでした。
Docker fileの内容は以下です(エラーになるのはわかります)

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

COPY C:\TEST\sample.txt /
```

そこでコンテナ作成後に`docker cp` を試したところ、ファイルはコピーできました。
そうなるとDocker fileでもできそうな気がするのですがどうなんでしょうか？？

※Hyper-V上に展開されたLinuxにファイルを置けばできるような気がするのですが
そのようなこと可能なのでしょうか？
それとも
SettingにShared Drivesがあるのですが、これでなんとかできるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Dockerfileでコピー元ファイルの指定を絶対パスではなくファイル名のみに変更してください。

   ```
   COPY sample.txt /
   ```
2. 対象のファイルが保存されているフォルダに移動します。

   ```
   cd C:\TEST\
   ```
3. Dokcerイメージをビルドします。

   ```
   docker build -t <image_name>
   ```

参考:
[Dockerfile COPY from a Windows file system to a docker container - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46309909/2322778) の回答より

Comment: 出来ました！とてつもなく初歩的な問題過ぎて、恥ずかしい限りです・・・。ありがとうございます！今本を見返したら、’「Dockerfileを含むすべてのディレクトリをDockerデーモンに転送する」’とありました・・・。読んでいるときはあまり理解していませんでしたが、今ようやく理解できました１